# Collapse Factors when their count is less than 25: ForCats R

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

I have a `Race` factor that has 34 levels. Since the counts in many levels are less than 20, I want to collapse them into a single category - "Other". Note that I already have `"Other"` as one level.

I see the documentation for `fct_collapse()` as you specifying the levels you want to collapse into one but not sure how to implement `count() < 20` in this. Perhaps a `case_when` but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fct_lump(f=factor, prop=0.05, other_level=“Other”)` to collapse levels that represent less than an specific percentage of the total. You can also use `n` instead of `prop` to specify the exact amount of levels you want, for example, 9 to get 9 levels + “Other”.